# control display with fbtft modules

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I would like to swap upside part and lower part in the display.
like this

| 1 | to  | 2 |
| 2 | to  | 1 |   upper half and lower half will be changed

so I have edited fbtft source (https://github.com/notro/fbtft/wiki/How-it-works, https://github.com/notro/fbtft)

I thought It is possible if I write the changed pixel value( pointer to current pixel value + half size ) in video memory when I send the data to 8 bit bus

my LCD is 240 X 320 resolution using SPI-8bit. device name is adafruit22a , driver name is ili9340.

this is the source I edited
first, in fbtft-core.c

```
 void fbtft_update_display(struct fbtft_par *par, unsigned start_line, unsigned end_line)void fbtft_update_display(struct fbtft_par *par, unsigned start_line, unsigned end_line)
{

 size_t offset, len;

 struct timespec ts_start, ts_end, ts_fps, ts_duration; 
 long fps_ms, fps_us, duration_ms, duration_us;
 long fps, throughput;  
 bool timeit = false;   
 int ret = 0;   
 unsigned start_line_t; // changed start line( startline + half size (119))

if (unlikely(par->debug & (DEBUG_TIME_FIRST_UPDATE | DEBUG_TIME_EACH_UPDATE))) {
    if ((par->debug & DEBUG_TIME_EACH_UPDATE) || \
            ((par->debug & DEBUG_TIME_FIRST_UPDATE) && !par->first_update_done)) {
        getnstimeofday(&ts_start);
        timeit = true;
    }
}

/* Sanity checks */
if (start_line > end_line) {
    dev_warn(par->info->device,
        "%s: start_line=%u is larger than end_line=%u. Shouldn't happen, will do full display update\n",
        __func__, start_line, end_line);
    start_line = 0;
    end_line = par->info->var.yres - 1;
}
if (start_line > par->info->var.yres - 1 || end_line > par->info->var.yres - 1) {
    dev_warn(par->info->device,
        "%s: start_line=%u or end_line=%u is larger than max=%d. Shouldn't happen, will do full display update\n",
        __func__, start_line, end_line, par->info->var.yres - 1);
    start_line = 0;
    end_line = par->info->var.yres - 1;
}

fbtft_par_dbg(DEBUG_UPDATE_DISPLAY, par, "%s(start_line=%u, end_line=%u)\n",
    __func__, start_line, end_line);

if (par->fbtftops.set_addr_win)
    par->fbtftops.set_addr_win(par, 0, start_line,
            par->info->var.xres-1, end_line);

start_line_t= (start_line + 119)%239;
//offset = start_line * par->info->fix.line_length;
offset = start_line_t * par->info->fix.line_length;
len = (end_line - start_line + 1) * par->info->fix.line_length;
ret = par->fbtftops.write_vmem(par, offset, len);
if (ret < 0)
    dev_err(par->info->device,
        "%s: write_vmem failed to update display buffer\n",
        __func__);

if (unlikely(timeit)) {
    getnstimeofday(&ts_end);
    if (par->update_time.tv_nsec == 0 && par->update_time.tv_sec == 0) {
        par->update_time.tv_sec = ts_start.tv_sec;
        par->update_time.tv_nsec = ts_start.tv_nsec;
    }
    ts_fps = timespec_sub(ts_start, par->update_time);
    par->update_time.tv_sec = ts_start.tv_sec;
    par->update_time.tv_nsec = ts_start.tv_nsec;
    fps_ms = (ts_fps.tv_sec * 1000) + ((ts_fps.tv_nsec / 1000000) % 1000);
    fps_us = (ts_fps.tv_nsec / 1000) % 1000;
    fps = fps_ms * 1000 + fps_us;
    fps = fps ? 1000000 / fps : 0;

    ts_duration = timespec_sub(ts_end, ts_start);
    duration_ms = (ts_duration.tv_sec * 1000) + ((ts_duration.tv_nsec / 1000000) % 1000);
    duration_us = (ts_duration.tv_nsec / 1000) % 1000;
    throughput = duration_ms * 1000 + duration_us;
    throughput = throughput ? (len * 1000) / throughput : 0;
    throughput = throughput * 1000 / 1024;

    dev_info(par->info->device,
        "Display update: %ld kB/s (%ld.%.3ld ms), fps=%ld (%ld.%.3ld ms)\n",
        throughput, duration_ms, duration_us,
        fps, fps_ms, fps_us);
    par->first_update_done = true;
}
    }
```

I changed start_line to start_line_t to move upper half to lower half.
then I write data from start_line_t to length in vedio memory (frame memory)

this is writing from video memory to bus in fbtft-bus.c

```
#define HALF_OF_LCD 119
#define END_OF_LCD 239

/* 16 bit pixel over 8-bit databus */
int fbtft_write_vmem16_bus8(struct fbtft_par *par, size_t offset, size_t len)
{
u16 *vmem16;
u16 *txbuf16 = (u16 *)par->txbuf.buf;
size_t remain;
size_t to_copy;
size_t tx_array_size;
int i;
int ret = 0;
size_t startbyte_size = 0;

size_t start_offset=0
size_t end_offset=0;
u16 *endMem16;

fbtft_par_dbg(DEBUG_WRITE_VMEM, par, "%s(offset=%zu, len=%zu)\n",
    __func__, offset, len);
end_offset= 239 * par->info->fix.line_length;
endMem16=(u16 *)(par->info->screen_base+ end_offset);
remain = len / 2;
vmem16 = (u16 *)(par->info->screen_base + offset);

if (par->gpio.dc != -1)
    gpio_set_value(par->gpio.dc, 1);

/* non buffered write */
if (!par->txbuf.buf)
    return par->fbtftops.write(par, vmem16, len);

/* buffered write */
tx_array_size = par->txbuf.len / 2;

if (par->startbyte) {
    txbuf16 = (u16 *)(par->txbuf.buf + 1);
    tx_array_size -= 2;
    *(u8 *)(par->txbuf.buf) = par->startbyte | 0x2;
    startbyte_size = 1;
}
while(remain)
{
    to_copy = remain > tx_array_size ? tx_array_size : remain;
    for (i = 0; i < to_copy; i++)
    {
        txbuf16[i] = cpu_to_be16(*vmem16);
        ++vmem16;
        if(vmem16 == endMem16)
            vmem16=(u16 *)(par->info->screen_base);
    }
    ret = par->fbtftops.write(par, par->txbuf.buf,
                    startbyte_size + to_copy * 2);
    if (ret < 0)
        return ret;
    remain -= to_copy;
}
return ret;
}
```

in the code if pointer get reached end of video memory address ,
it moves to initial address in video memory address.( lower half should be written in upper half side).

the result is showing what I want like swapped half display
but the problem is that mouse moving and update display are so slow
even mouse is disappeared in upper half side.
I dont know what is wrong and how should I edit the part of source
I want to control display with frame buffer
anyone help me ? T^T

Comment: First of all, the driver is in upstream under drivers/staging/fbtft. Instead of copy'n'pasting entire pieces of code, please, fork kernel sources on your github account, create your sandbox branch, make a change, submit it to that branch and share the link to the branch.

Comment: this is [my repo](https://github.com/ImYeol/linux_fbtft)

Comment: And how can I see your changes? You may and must fork the existing repository which called torvalds/linux, then might be needed to add linux-next tree to it, and so on which I already described

Comment: oh sorry . this is [fork repo](https://github.com/ImYeol/linux/tree/test1/drivers/staging/fbtft) or [fork repo2](https://github.com/ImYeol/fbtft)

Comment: Okay, if you see what you want to see, means probably no problem with your code. Do I understand correctly you have not the issue before you trying your changes?

Comment: Yeah before I changed , there were no problems. But since I changed source , mouse moving is updated late and disappeared in upper half. I dont know how I should check what it is wrong...